# Как в Laravel или PHP настроить Timezone чтобы приложение автоматически переходило на летнее время?

Tags: php, laravel

В Laravel-е   время отстает  на один час,

Timezon   правильно задана,  как понял это связанно с летним временем и DST,

Помогите разобраться с этим  установить Timezone другой местности не хочу, но если это повсеместная практика то сделаю ?

Comment: а какое время у вас указано на сервере?

Comment: Это локальный сервер , как понимаю время он получает из  настроек компютера.

Comment: версия пыхи какая?

Comment: версия  PHP 7.1.11